# How to convert a UTC date string to timezone aware datetime object in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime

I have a UTC format date string represented as :

```
ds = "2019-06-15 17:18:06 UTC"
```

I am trying to convert it into a python utc datetime object like this :

```
d = datetime.strptime(ds,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

However I am getting the following error :

```
ValueError: time data '2019-06-15 17:18:06 UTC' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

So what is the correct format to pass, so that I get a datetime object in UTC timezone?

Answer (score 1):

Use format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
import pytz

ds = "2019-06-15 17:18:06 UTC"
nDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(ds,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z') 
timezone = pytz.timezone(ds.split()[-1])
d_aware = timezone.localize(nDate)
print(d_aware)
print(d_aware.tzinfo)
```

**Output:**

```
2019-06-15 17:18:06+00:00
UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

The format string you are currently using doesn't match with the datetime string format which you provided. That's why its throwing error.

```
 datetime.strptime(ds,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC')
```

Comment: Using this format string, the resulting object is not timezone aware. Of course if you know your input is UTC, this can be handled manually, but is there a way to automatically parse the `UTC` marker? Notice that using `d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')` on a timezone aware object will generate the `UTC` marker, and `datetime.strptime(ds,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')` will consume it, but the resulting object is *not* timezone aware.